# How can I get current price for UniSwap token?

Tags: uniswap, polygon

I have a token I created on the Polygon mainnet and am providing liquidity through Uniswap.

I need to programmatically fetch the current price to use in my tipping widget.

Is there an API for this?
I would like to get price in USD and EUR or at least ETH or BTC so I can convert.